# Set R bookdown input directory

Tags: r, bookdown

I'd like to use bookdown to parse a series of `.Rmd` file into a book. If I have my `.Rmd` in the same directory as the main `index.Rmd` file then everything works fine and dandy. However, the `.Rmd` files are autogenerated from another source and I'd like to keep the input files in a subdirectory. Is it possible to do that?

I can include the file names in `_bookdown.yml` but I'd prefer not having to update that file every time a new `.Rmd` file is added.

The current version of `_bookdown.yml` looks like this

```
new_session: yes
rmd_files:
  html: ["input/index.Rmd", "input/01-file.Rmd"]
  latex: ["input/index.Rmd", "input/01-file.Rmd"]
```

I can move the files in a script but was hoping it was possible through `bookdown` itself.

Comment: You can set `rmd_subdir` to `true` so Rmd files in subdirectories are also used and you do not have to explicitly list them in `rmd_files`: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/configuration.html

Comment: Ah yes thank you. But that searches through *all* subdirectories. Is it possible to name specific sub directories as, e.g., `rmd_subdir: [ 'input/' ]`. In any case your comment answered my immediate question.

Comment: That is not possible for now, but it sounds like a useful feature to be added. You can file a feature request to https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the development version of bookdown you can now provide a list of subdirectories to be search recursively.

For example to have it search `dir1/` and `dir2/` (and their subdirectories) you can specify `rmd_subdir: ["dir1/", "dir2/"]` in the `_bookdown.yml`.

Comment: hi Ellis, do you know if this is now available in bookdown 0.7? I can't get it working. Created a new bookdown project via Rstudio, copied all (except index.Rmd) to new folder and set the rmd_subdir: ["new_folder"]. However only the index.Rmd is shown. Note I am running under windows maybe that is the problem. I have asked this question also on stackoverflow

Comment: @FlorisPadt I have answered your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51735752/559676