# Can't get bookdown rmd_subdir ["dir"] to work

Tags: r, yaml, bookdown

I tried to use the new rmd_subdir option in the _bookdown.yml by setting a list of subdirectories. I copied all files except the index.Rmd of a freshly created bookdown project in a folder called **content**. The following setting in the _bookdown.yml does work

```
rmd_subdir: = yes
```

However when I change the _bookdown.yml to the following only the index.Rmd is compiled.

#### _bookdown.yml

```
book_filename: "_tmp_rmd_subdir"
delete_merged_file: true
language:
  ui:
    chapter_name: "Chapter "
rmd_subdir: ["content"]
```

> R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
>   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale:
>   [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252
>   [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
>   [5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252
>
> attached base packages:
>   [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>    [1] Rcpp_0.12.15    bookdown_0.7    digest_0.6.14   rprojroot_1.3-2 backports_1.1.2
>    [6] magrittr_1.5    evaluate_0.10.1 stringi_1.1.6   rstudioapi_0.7  rmarkdown_1.9
>   [11] tools_3.4.3     stringr_1.3.0   tinytex_0.4     xfun_0.1        yaml_2.1.19
>   [16] rsconnect_0.8.5 compiler_3.4.3  htmltools_0.3.6 knitr_1.20

Comment: As of July 2020 this is still broken. Steps to duplicate: 1) Create a fresh bookdown project in Rstudio. 2) Build a gitbook with no modifications = Success. 3) Create directory in project named "corpus" 4) add ' rmd_subdir: ["corpus"] ' to _bookdown.yml. 5) build a gitbook = failure with "output file: bookdown_test.knit.md. Error: Input files not all in same directory, please supply explicit wd. Execution halted "

Answer (score 1):

This [should be fixed](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/pull/601) in the development version of **bookdown**. Please try

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/bookdown')
```